# Is there a way to see if two lists are the exact same without looping in python?

Tags: python

Say I have:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3]
```

is there a way to test the lists to see if they are the same, without having to loop through each entry?

Here's what I was thinking..I know to check if two variables are the same I could use:

```
id(a)
```

but it doesn't work because the ID's are different so is there some type of checksum or way that python stores values of the table so I can simply compare two variables?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Doesn't `==` work?

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a == b
True
```

Comment: I'm so sorry..I must be sleepy. I didn't think of that.  I was thinking of nesting for loops,etc..Thank you..

Answer (score 3):

the `==` operator should function as expected on lists

```
>>> x = [1, 2]  
>>> y = [1, 2]
>>> x == y
True
```

Answer (score 0):

the == operator should function works on lists

*This output is received on certain versions of python, I don't know which.*

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]  
>>> y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> z = [1, 2, 2, 4]
>>> x == y
[True, True, True, True]
>>> x == z
[True, True, False, True]
```

After this, just use numpy to determine the entire list.

```
>>> np.all(x == y)
True
>>> np.all(x == z)
False
```

---

or if only a single similarity is required:

```
>>> np.any(x == z)
True
```